# How To count total number of members on my Discord server by python

Tags: discord.py

i'm trying this code but it is not working

```
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def myid(ctx):
    print(ctx.guild.member_count)

client.run(my token)
```

can you provide me right code

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @aiyan its not responding.... a blank waiting window comming

Comment: `client` isn't defined here.  Usually, `client` would be an instance of `commands.Bot` and you would use the `client.command` decorator instead of `commands.command`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the problem statement, if we need to find name of total members of our servers. then use this code.

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
token = 'your token'

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    users = client.users 
    print(users)
    #or
    guilds = client.get_guild        
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild.name)
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

As what Patrick Haugh said, you did not define your client yet. Also, pass_context is no longer needed in discord rewrite.

The most basic code would look something like this:

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'PREFIX')

@client.command()
async def myid(ctx):
    print(ctx.guild.member_count)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Where `PREFIX` is whatever command prefix you want and `TOKEN` is your bot token

I suggest reading the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def members(ctx):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=f'There Are {ctx.guild.member_count} Members In This Server', color=0xFF0000)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

This also works but sends in server, not console.